# Android http Post Login

Tags: php, android, json, http, authentication

I'm trying to make a login to my website via an Android app. For some reason something always goes wrong.

**Here's my site login structure:**

**Login.php** - the login form (username & password)

**Auth.php** - login authentication page (gets the username & password from page - login.php (POST method))
I already have to interface with Username & Password (`EditText` both)

What is the method to make a login via android app?

**here's my current login method:**

```
private void login() {

         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://url/auth.php");  
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

           try {  

               List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(2);  
               jsonObject.put("action", "login");
               jsonObject.put("username", "user1");
               jsonObject.put("password", "12345");

               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonString", jsonObject.toString()));               

               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


               String responseStr = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

               statusText.setText(responseStr);
           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
               statusText.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
           } catch (IOException e) {   
               statusText.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
           } catch (JSONException e) {

           }

    }
```

**Edit:**

I merged both pages (login & auth) to one page, when I call the method, responseStr get the entire page html code.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting with this code?

Comment: I don't get any errors or exceptions

Comment: You have mentioned that something always goes wrong. The code you have pasted seems to be correct. Are you not getting the response you are looking for?

Comment: When I try to login I get this in the statusText:
org.apache.http.conn@BasicManagedEntity@[some code always changes]

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, but isn't encoding the data as JSON overkill? You already have a method for transmitting name-value pairs!

Comment: Thank you for your patience, maybe it's overkill but I'm working on this login method for 3 days.
org.apache.http.conn@BasicManagedEntity is what I get for response.getEntity().toString()
Beyond that I don't get any errors or exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't log the response body with the toString method.

The object returned in the responseEntity can be read as an InputStream or more simply, converted to a string with the EntityUtils class.

```
String responseStr = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Try logging the responseStr.